# Is it correct way to log the open connections using CachingClientConnectionFactory

Tags: spring-integration, spring-integration-ip

I am implementing TCP Client. I am using CachingClientConnectionFactory to create pool of 10 TCP Connections using `TcpNetClientConnectionFactory`. I am aiming to print connection ids of open-connections. I came across cachingClientConnectionFactory.[`getOpenConnectionIds()`](https://docs.spring.io/spring-integration/api/org/springframework/integration/ip/tcp/connection/AbstractConnectionFactory.html#getOpenConnectionIds())

But it does not print anything. On digging in deeper, I found that neither `CachingClientConnectionFactory` nor `AbstractClientConnectionFactory` provide the implementation for `getOpenConnectionIds()`. In fact, it is implemented in `AbstractConnectionFactory`. So, it's safe to assume that the method is only applicable to TCP Server?

I am all ears to other suggestion to print connection ids of open connections on client side. For time being, I am leveraging `cachingClientConnectionFactory.getActiveCount()` to print the number of open/active connections.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please open an issue on GitHub, referencing this question.

The method is supported on both client and server connection factories, but the delegating factories (such as the `CachingClientConnectionFactory` which delegates to a "real" client factory) currently do not support the method.

One thing you can do to work around it is to add an `@EventListener` to receive events when connections are opened and closed.

https://docs.spring.io/spring-integration/docs/current/reference/html/ip.html#tcp-events